# Why “cerr << s ;” output different string to s, while console's output adds "1*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*" wizard characters?

Tags: c++, string, io, console

I've debugged the program and seen `s == "101111000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101111000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`
But in the console, it outputs `"1*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*101111000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101111000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`
which just adds wizard characters of `"1*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*"`
The code to produce the output:

```
UINT8 sMessage[4096];
memset(sMessage, 0, 4096);

Num_Thread = 0;
OutputNum_Thread = 0;

EncodeInitiatedTestCommandActionSet(&InitiatedTestCommandACTION, sMessage);//fill sMessage with "0101...0101..."

string s = (char*)sMessage;

cerr << s << "\n";
```

(using QT)

Comment: What is a "wizard character"? Do you mean "wildcard"? Anyway, this might be an encoding issue, if the string is built in a different encoding from what the console expects.

Comment: @unwind, I mean odd or strange characters which confuse me.

Comment: try `copy( s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator< int >( cout, ", " ) );` instead of `cerr << s`

Comment: @unwind, the string is just a char[] filled with chars.

Comment: @borisbn, it outputs: 1*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*1*0*1*1*1*1*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*0*49, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48,...

Comment: Are you **really** shure, that this is the first and the last output using `cout` (or `cerr`) in your programm ? Try to write a very little test

Comment: Maybe `EncodeInitiatedTestCommandActionSet` writes to `cerr`... Try to output your string to file with `ofstream`